# Retrieving User Name in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, variables

How does Sharepoint retrieve the user's actual name as displayed in the top right corner? e.g `Welcome John Smith`

I need to call this name as a variable or parameter on custom code in the XSL editor but I can't figure out how I can retrieve it, is it a global variable?

Comment: @Eton-B.: This is not an XSLT question, please, do not tag it as such. You may try the xsltprocessors tag, although I doubt it even falls in that category.

Comment: How is it not? I need to know how to do this via XSL ...

Comment: Where are you using XSL? We need some more information about what you're attempting to do.

Comment: I'm working with a data view web part that already had some custom code in the XSL Editor, but there's a string comparison that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a user's account name using the server variable [LOGON_USER](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spdsupport/archive/2008/07/25/data-view-data-form-parameters-you-don-t-know-about.aspx). However, this doesn't return a user's Display name.

I was able to get something working which a combination of web parts to display their name:

1. Add a `UserContextFilterWebPart` (you may need to enable this web part in the web part gallery).
2. Add a DataView webpart which queries the `GetUserInfo` method (part of the UserGroup.asmx web service).

   - a. Click "Connect to a web service..." in the Data Source Library pane under XML Web Services
   - b. Enter the Service description location (the URL to the UserGroup web service). Ex: `http://server/sites/SiteCollection/SubSite/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?WSDL`
   - c. Click Connect (or reconnect)
   - d. Choose `GetUserInfo` for the Operation dropdown (the other dropdowns should be ok)
   - e. Modify the userLoginName parameter and check the box to allow the value to be set via web part connection. I also added a default value to test (ex: domain\login).
   - f. Click OK.
   - g. Click on the data source and click Show Data
   - h. Choose the columns you need and then drag them onto the page
3. Connect them together using web part connections (UserContext provided to the DataView).

Comment: Hi! It seems that this is the answer I need. However, could you elaborate on #2 please?

Comment: Sure thing! I added more detailed steps for #2.

Comment: Thanks, sure seems like this will fix my problem. However, upon adding the UserContextFilter web part I started getting a "403 Forbidden" error on that page, even with admin user. I'm not sure what's causing that...

Comment: I got the display name using a CAML variable "UserID"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SPServices (which is great, btw):

```
function getCurrentUsersName(){
var firstName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "FirstName",
    debug: false
});
return firstName;
}

function getCurrentUsersLastName(){
var lastName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "LastName",
    debug: false
});
return lastName;
}
```

You can look up a host of other similar fieldnames [here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser):

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's coming in through NTLM Authentication/Active Directory.  I ususally get login name DOMAIN/User in the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name field, and then match against Active Directory and bring back the actual name of the user.

Answer (score 0):

SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName will give you the value for the login name of the current user, as displayed in the top right of a standard portal.

If you want to use this with XSLT, you need to find a way of assigning this to an XSL parameter value at run-time.